# How do I replace characters using Javascript in HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html

For example I have a string getting from current URL using javascript

> hostname/report/searchDate?searchOrderID=&searchDateFrom=2018-10-16&searchDateTo=2018-10-23&search=search&sortBy=OrderDateAsc

How do I replace character in the end `OrderDateAsc` ? If I want to replace for example , `OrderDateDesc` , how should I do it using Javascript ? The URL infront might be differs all the time , they keyword should be `&sortBy`.
Please help ,thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
var url = new URL(currentUrl);
var c = url.searchParams.get("sortBy");
```

You can get sortBy value like this, and maybe you can use some if statements for if set or not , and you can set like this:

```
url.searchParams.set('sortBy',"WhateverYouWant");
```

Also,convert url to string, you can read parameters `url.searchParams.get("sortBy");` and again some if statements,

if change :

```
url = url.Replace(sortByValue,"WhateverYouWant");
```

this will works too. 
But if your string looks like that and you try to change search value, then you will change every "search" value and its not work. :

```
hostname/report/searchDate?searchOrderID=&searchDateFrom=2018-10-16&searchDateTo=2018-10-23&search=search&sortBy=OrderDateAsc
```

change search as WhateverYouWant

```
hostname/report/WhateverYouWantDate?WhateverYouWantOrderID=&WhateverYouWantDateFrom=2018-10-16&WhateverYouWantDateTo=2018-10-23&WhateverYouWant=WhateverYouWant&sortBy=OrderDateAsc
```

You see, its bad :)

Comment: i'm not replacing sortby , instead the parameter behind it

Comment: `sortBy` was just an example. this will always be your parametres and you will always know this parametres names, isnt it ?

Comment: var url = new URL(currentUrl);
var c = url.searchParams.get("sortBy"); doesn't work , it doesn't return anything

Comment: Which browser you are working with ? Internet Explorer ?

Comment: and maybe your `currentUrl` variable is `undefined`. Because in my example its  current Url on browser, `var currentUrl = Window.location.href;`

Comment: using firefox , the currentURl is correct ,  there is a value , then starting from new URL it doesn't return value

Comment: please check this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL#Example)

Comment: open browser console and write this code in here, `var currentUrl = window.location.href;
    var url = new URL(currentUrl);
url` and just enter it. you will see `url` is not `empty` or `undefined` or `null`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with the following code.

```
//your string
let str = "hostname/report/searchDate?searchOrderID=&searchDateFrom=2018-10-16&searchDateTo=2018-10-23&search=search&sortBy=OrderDateAsc";
//find "OrderDateAsc" and replace it with "OrderDateDesc"
str = str.replace("OrderDateAsc", "OrderDateDesc" );
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use regular expression and replace the sortBy param value like that:

```
const url ='hostname/report/searchDate?searchOrderID=&searchDateFrom=2018-10-16&searchDateTo=2018-10-23&search=search&sortBy=OrderDateAsc';
const regex = /(&sortBy=OrderDate)(Asc)/gi;
const newUrl = url.replace(regex, '$1Desc');
```